# Any way to use Xcode 3 with iOS SDK 4.3?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, sdk

I'm using Xcode 4 with iOS 4.3. Xcode 4 is very buggy, not to mention a lot of stuff changed. The changes that most bug me are the hot keys, which I cannot even find a way to customize them in a decent combination. I'd love to use Xcode 3 because it's stable and it does what I need. Is there anyway to use Xcode 3 with iOS 4.3?

Comment: I'm tempted to switch back myself... so many little annoyances, along with the few-times-a-day crash...

Comment: You do realize that you can change all of the key bindings within the Key Bindings tab in Xcode 4's Preferences?

Comment: @Brad - Yes, I know they can be changed, but why are they using default keys that don't even work easily on a macbook? E.g. debugger stepping keys. What is wrong with the Xcode 3 bindings?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go to the [iOS Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action), and under the Xcode 4 + iOS SDK 4.3 download link you should find an Xcode 3.2.6 + iOS SDK 4.3 download link. If you don't see it you may need to log in first.

Here it is:

[image]

Comment: Do you REALLY have to download both the iOS SDK AND XCode??