# Where is the Interface Builder in the MonoDevelop application?

Tags: iphone, ipad, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm having a play around with MonoTouch [for the very first time](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgkOCJ9PGkk). In the [Hello World tutorial](http://monotouch.net/Tutorials/MonoDevelop_HelloWorld) for Noobs-Like-Me, it says the following:

> Launch Interface Builder by double-clicking on the MainWindow.xib file. Once Interface Builder starts up, you should see a surface (your window) and a Library that contains various components. Your Library should look like the following screenshot. If it is not there, select Library from the Tools menu

When I try that, nothing happens. No new 'window' shows. If I go to the Tools menu, there is no option for Library.

The solution type I made was a `C# iPhone Window-based Project`.

Comment: have you tried < command+shift+L > ?

Comment: I have now - and it's not showing up/anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interface Builder is part of the iOS SDK made available to developers by Apple; it is not part of MonoTouch or the MonoDevelop IDE. If nothing happens when you try to open a `.xib` file, IB may not be installed on your Mac.

To obtain it, go to [the iOS Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios) and download Xcode 3.2.6 and iOS SDK. Make sure you download Xcode 3 and not Xcode 4, as IB is only a separate application in version 3. Quoting from [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331168/xcode-3-and-ios-sdk-4-3/5331232#5331232) to find the Xcode 3 download link:

> ... under the Xcode 4 + iOS SDK 4.3 download link you should find an Xcode 3.2.6 + iOS SDK 4.3 download link. If you don't see it you may need to log in first.
>
> Here it is:
>
> [image]

Comment: Whoa! haha - so hold on a sec. You're saying that the latest version of Xcode (at the time of this post) does not include IB ?

Comment: @Pure Krome: Yeah, IB is baked right into the Xcode IDE. See http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html#interface-builder

Comment: @BoltClock - hmm. but i've installed Xcode 4 .. so if IB is baked in .. then it should be there, right? Is there a way I can check what Xcode things are installed?

Comment: @BoltClock - ok.. so where do i find the download for IB .. now that i'm confirming that i'm using 3.2.6 ..??

Comment: @Pure.Krome: Hmmm, strange. Look in /Developer/Applications and see if you can find IB?

Comment: @BoltClock - got it ;) for some weird reason, when I first installed 3.2.6, it didn't install the 8gig SDK .. only the 1.something Gig something.. *blush* .. a -reinstall- fixed it (and that's when i noticed that the main sdk wasn't installed!)

Comment: Note, you can keep Xcode 4.0.1 installed in /Developer and then specifically install Xcode 3.2.6 to /Xcode3 or something. If you then set /Xcode3/Applications/Interface Builder as the default handler for xib files, everything in MD should work fine.